# How do i create a remote repository from a local repository in Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, cmd

Hi Guys i'm using visual studio 2019 and i'm trying to learn how can i create a remote repository on a local server without using github so other people can work on it (we are in the same room), i'm trying to use only visual studio, git  and the cmd

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, what you want is **to host your instance of a repository**.

You need to configure your instance in a server that is accesible to all of the developers that you expect to collaborate with you. You used the tag [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) which leads me to think you are under Windows. You may use Windows as server, but you may probably be better off with a Linux distro in your server (the machine where you intend to develop may use any OS you want). One option (I'm not affiliated with) is [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/install/) which has a good documentation on how to deploy your instance in several flavors of Linux, as well as some cloud services, docker, kubernetes. If you decide to stick to Windows, probably something docker-based or kubernetes-based is your option.

Be aware, however, that you don't have to stick to GitLab. There are plenty of self-hosted, open-source Git servers such as:

- [gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/)
- [GNU Savannah](https://savannah.gnu.org/)
- [GitBucket](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket) (yes, their source code is in GitHub and no, it's not bitbucket)
- [gogs](https://gogs.io/)

and many more alternatives... try looking for "self-hosted git server" and you may find many other options

Disclaimer: I don't vouch for any of the tools in this answer nor am I responsible for their malfunction should you choose one of them, I merely looked for several of them. It's your job to see which one fits your use case best